# Android: File not found on external storage

Tags: android, file, path, storage

I have a string *filename* which is a path to the pictures folder on external storage for android deveices. I am using the string to save an image with opencv.
Then I want to send a share intent to share the saved image with other apps.

```
Highgui.imwrite(filename, Image);
Log.d("WRITEPATH", filename);
```

In LogCat I get for WRITEPATH:

> /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyImages/Image1.jpg

Then I convert the filepath-string to an uri:

```
Uri lastsavedUri=Uri.parse(new File(filename).toString())
```

And send my share intent:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, SavedImages);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share images to.."));
```

*SavedImages* is a ArrayList containing multiple *lastsavedUri*

Unfortunately no app can find the images I am trying to share. For example Gmail crashes after clicking send mail and I receive a logcat error

> 10-07 10:19:47.265: E/Gmail(26264): Unable to get orientation of
>   thumbnail /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyImages/Image1.jpg 10-07
>   10:19:47.265: E/Gmail(26264): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No
>   content provider: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyImages/Image1.jpg

Why can I save my images using the filepath string but why can't I share the saved images? Is the path not correct and how do I get the correct path to my saved images?

Comment: Does `Highgui.imwrite` close the file handle?

Comment: What is `SavedImages` in your intent extra stream ?

Comment: I am not 100% sure if Highgui.imwrite closes the file handle. I couldn't find information on opencv site. Is it possible to close file handle using android tools?

Comment: `SavedImages` is a ArrayList containing multiple lastsavedUri. `ArrayList<Uri>SavedImages = new ArrayList<Uri>();` and then `SavedImages.add(lastsavedUri);` in a for loop

Comment: I don't know if this is any help, but I checked if the saved File exists and if the file is readable. Result for both is true. But when I use `file.canExecutable()` I get false and I also get false by executing `file.setExecuteable(true,false)`. I don't know if this causes my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried

```
File saveFile = new File(filename);
SavedImages.add(Uri.fromFile(saveFile));
```

instead of

```
Uri lastsavedUri=Uri.parse(new File(filename).toString())
SavedImages.add(lastsavedUri);
```

and now it is working. I don't understand why, but it works.